# pmap size vs rss when it can't be disk

Tags: linux, memory, pmap

When I run pmap, I see a lot of segments like:

```
     Address Perm   Offset Device    Inode       Size    Rss    Pss Referenced Anonymous Swap Locked Mapping
7fdb7c000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00        0        132      4      4          4         4    0      0
```

There's 128kB that aren't in RAM (that'd be Rss), aren't in swap (that's zero, plus it's disabled on this machine) and aren't left on disk as a named file (this segment doesn't mmap a file).  So what are they?

Comment: It's the text segment? This is mapped to the executable and libraries.

Comment: @Barmar isn't the text segment at the bottom of memory, permissioned as executable, and mapped to the executable file?

Comment: There are multiple text segments because of dynamic libraries.

Comment: I see lots of dynamic libraries explicitly listed as Mapping to those files.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of that memory block to see if anything looks familiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's 128kB that aren't in RAM (that'd be Rss), aren't in swap (that's zero, plus it's disabled on this machine) and aren't left on disk as a named file (this segment doesn't mmap a file).

They aren't on *any* device, as device number `00:00` tells you.  So, for example, they aren't on a raw disk partition, either.

> So what are they?

They are not mapped to any device and they are not resident in memory, so they can only be purely virtual.  They exhibit the kernel having assigned virtual memory to the process that is not (yet) associated with any actual storage.  This is a thing that happens.